# C++ Memory Leak - interpreting analysis

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I'm having a memory leak in the following piece of c++ code:

```
void onNewDepthSample(DepthNode node, DepthNode::NewSampleReceivedData data)
{
    INT32 w, h;
    FrameFormat_toResolution(data.captureConfiguration.frameFormat, &w, &h);
    INT32 size = data.depthMap.size();

    int16_t* ptr = new int16_t[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            ptr[i] = data.depthMap[i];
        }

    depthCB(stringToCsharpString(node.getSerialNumber()), &w, &h, ptr);
    delete[] ptr;   
}
```

this method is called 30 times per second. Memory Leak Analysis:

```
Function details

Function   DepthsenseDriver!malloc+49 
Source Line    
Allocation type   Heap allocation(s) 
Heap handle   0xcf11e4ac 
Allocation Count   75256 allocation(s) 
Allocation Size   1,22 MBytes 
Leak Probability   100%



Call stack sample 1

Address   0x32335344 
Allocation Time   00:05:00 since tracking started 
Allocation Size   17 Bytes 


Call stack:

DepthsenseDriver!malloc+49   
DepthsenseDriver!operator new+1d
DepthsenseDriver!CreateFileW+96b    
DepthsenseDriver!DepthSense::FunctionHandler<DepthSense::DepthNode,DepthSense::DepthNode::NewSampleReceivedData>::operator()+5d
```

I would like to know how I can interprete this analysis. For example, there is a CreateFileW function call, but in my code, this function call does not exist.

I am a C++ noob, so every tip or improvement is welcome :)

Comment: What is `FrameFormat_toResolution`? Can you please add more details. Appears like this type has `operator ()` overloaded which may expect some cleanup or is buggy.

Comment: It might also be a leaker detector's bug. Try with a vector and see if that reproduces.

Comment: You can also double check with valgrind or leak sanitizer. But I don't see why do you think that the leak is in this function which I don't see in the leak report. I would have suggested the function CreateFileW

Comment: @Brahim I don't call a function CreateFileW in my DepthsenseDriver project... I don't understand why this function is in the analysis result.

Comment: Looks like it's in `depthCB` and some of the stack is missing from the report.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Deleaker](http://deleaker.com), I discovered it was the stringToCsharpString method which caused the leak.